# Using custom media queries with Neat

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

The [documentation grid-media on Neat 2.0.0](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/2.0.0/#grid-media) describes the ability to set a media query in pixels. By default, this will output a pixel value as a `min-width` media query.

For example:

```
$custom-neat-grid: (
  columns: 12,
  gutter: 50px,
  media: 1000px,
);

.element {
  @include grid-column(3);

  @include grid-media($custom-neat-grid){
    @include grid-column(6);
  }
}
```

will output to:

```
.element {
  width: calc(25% - 25px);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .element {
    width: calc(50% - 75px);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
```

How can I use grid-media in Neat with other media query attributes like max-width or height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out how to achieve this.

You can pass a full media query to the `media` parameter of a [custom grid](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/2.0.0/#custom-grids).

An example:

```
$custom-neat-grid: (
  columns: 12,
  gutter: 50px,
  media: 'only screen and (max-width: 600px)',
);
```